# is it possible to create a bean using new() without making its inner beans unusable?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

I'm using Weld for CDI.
I'm looking for a way to run a periodic thread which includes injected beans.

In main i want to create:

```
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ExampleThread(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

where ExampleThread is:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleThread implements Runnable {

    @Inject
    private SomeBean someBean;


    public ExampleThread() {}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        someBean.do();
    }
}
```

The issue is that once i create the ExampleThread using new() it makes its inner beans unusable.
Is there a way to create the ExampleThread in a way that will work?

Comment: The answers provide some valid pointers - my preference would be to pass the dependencies through the constructor. But can you provide more information on *why exactly do you want the `Runnable` to be created anew* with every scheduled execution? I have the impression that using an injected instance of the `@ApplicationScoped` bean itself might suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the bean this way:

```
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ExampleThread(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and in the ExampleThread initialize the bean in the following way:

```
public class ExampleThread implements Runnable
{
    private SomeBean someBean;

    public ExampleThread()
    {
        this.someBean = CDI.current().select(SomeBean.class).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        someBean.do();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply inject a provider instead of using new:

```
@Inject
private Provider<ExampleThread> exampleThreadProvider;

...

executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(exampleThreadProvider.get(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than the accepted answer, as it just uses pure injection everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead pass a reference of the CDI bean to the runnable object via its constructor. Something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Foo
{
    @Inject
    private SomeBean someBean;

    // ...

    public void someMethod()
    {
        // ...
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new ExampleThread(someBean), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

```
public class ExampleThread implements Runnable
{
    private SomeBean someBean;

    public ExampleThread(SomeBean someBean)
    {
        this.someBean = someBean;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        someBean.do();
    }
}
```